# Refresh the page smoothly

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to make my desired div element visible in the template using a *ngIf directive. I don't wanna do it using reload() function cause it reloads the whole page.

I wanna change my html content based on language that is dynamically changed by clicking on onChangeLang() function. This function change the language values(e.g: bn, en) but it does not reflect the html template. But it works when I use reload() function which is not expected.

Thanks in advance...

TEMPLATE

```
<button (click)="onChangeLang()">Change Language</button>

<div *ngIf= "lang === 'en'">
   <p>I love walking.</p>
</div>

<div *ngIf= "lang === 'bn'">
   <p>I love reading history books.</p>
</div>
```

SCRIPT

```
lang: string;

onChangeLang() {
    return (this.lang === 'bn' ? 'en' : 'bn');
}


I expect <p> element to be changed smoothly not reloading the entire page.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to update the `lang` variable in the `onChangeLang()` method. This will trigger the binding and tell angular to revalidate the ngIf condition.

```
lang: string;

onChangeLang() {
    // emulate toggle behaviour
    this.lang = (this.lang === 'bn' ? 'en' : 'bn');
}


I expect <p> element to be changed smoothly not reloading the entire page.
```

Comment: It works well. My scenario is a bit different that I had not showed in my question.

There are 2 components:
1. top-bar.component ( I talked about before)
2.home.component.

(Top-bar contains the the onChangeLang() function and home.component has the lang property).

Here, I need to reflect the lang property of the home.component as the home template needs to be changed as well based on the lang value. Assume that the home template is similar to the top-bar template.

Thanks again, sir.